# Como tentar deixar um site compatível com os principais browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Ainda não tenho muita experiência e queria saber dicas sobre o que fazer para aumentar as chances de que um site seja compatível com a maioria dos browsers.

Comment: Bom primeiramente é essencial que você aprenda Html e Css. Com o html você fará a parte que chamamos de marcação (esqueleto do site) e com o Css você vai lapidar o visual do seu site. É importante que seu sites sejam feitos usando divs e não tabelas assim rodara perfeitamente em qualquer navegador sem problemas. Essa técnica das divs se chama tableless. Comece estudando nesse site http://www.w3schools.com/html/ é gratuito e você vai aprender muita coisa legal. Boa sorte.

Comment: A única solução é evitar usar tecnologias avançadas usar coisas bem simples se quiser manter compatível com navegadores mais antigos.... Se o caso for todos browsers modernos apenas ie11, edge, Firefox, chrome vai depender da tecnologia estar implementada no navegador ou não. Não existe fórmula mágica e nem pronta pra isto, o jeito é indo testando em quanto constrói em todos navegadores pra evitar dor de cabeça.

Comment: Depende do site. O que tem nele? Se tiver Flash ou Java ele nunca será compatível com todos. Por outro lado você pode ter um site basicamente composto de texto, nesse caso ele é automaticamente compatível com todos os navegadores. Também depende do que você entende por compatível. Vários sites são legíveis em todos os navegadores, embora apresentem diferenças de comportamento e de visualização. Ainda assim, sempre que você usar alguma coisa além do mais trivial, sempre vai ter aquele usuário acessando com IE6 ou celular antigo. Resumo: não tem solução nem dica que faça milagres.

Answer (score 3):

Gilmar , a questão de manter compatibilidade com todos os browsers é muito ampla.

**Sobre o funcionamento dos browsers:**

Quando você digita um endereço na barra de navegação , clica em um botão que envia um formulário,links... você envia uma requisição(geralmente usando o protocolo **http**) pra um servidor, que entendendo o seu pedido te retorna os arquivos correspondentes .

Você pode receber diversos tipos de arquivos(html,css,xml,javascript,txt..) e o browser vai interpretar e gerar uma representação visual dessa interpretação.

**Mas ele interpreta / exibe do jeito que quer ?**

**Não !**  Ou pelo menos não deve.

Existem padrões a serem seguidos e a [W3C](https://www.w3.org/) é a principal organização reguladora.

O browser deve gerar o conteudo que agente ve do jeitinho que o padrão especifica !

**E na prática ? Isso funciona mesmo ?**

`Na maioria dos casos SIM !` O problema é que vez ou outra , pedacinhos de código podem ser interpretados de maneira distinta e zonear tudo. Nesses casos que você vai ter que alterar ou escrever um código específico pra browsers distintos .

Além disso , esse padrão com o tempo é alterado a medida que novas tecnologias e necessidades vão surgindo .

Os primeiros browsers eram capazes de interpretar somente uma versão mais simples e bem grosseira do HTML ! Estamos entrando na era da **WEB 3.0** e toda hora surge uma nova tecnologia que é suportada somente pelos browsers mais recentes .

**E então como fazer ?**

Existem uma série de boas práticas a serem seguidas, geralmente nos cursos e tutoriais elas vão ser passadas !

É muito comum usar plugins , APIS , frameworks.. de terceiros e nesses casos é legal usar aqueles que sabemos que são bem suportados pelos principais browsers, bons exemplos são [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) e o maravilhoso  [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) .

E minha última dica é que na medida que for desenvolvendo, teste o site nos browsers que deseja compatibilidade e alguma coisa saindo diferente entre eles , pesquise pra encontrar a solução .

Comment: Então para alguns estilos tenho que colocar prefixos (-moz-, -webkit- e etc.)

Comment: @GilmarSantos principalmente nas novidades do HTML 5 que ainda estão sendo padronizadas . Analisando os 3 principais browsers , Chrome e Firefox tem andado juntos e os códigos tem sido bem compatíveis entre eles ! E o Internet Explorer parece que ainda está na guerra dos navegadores... não quer suportar certos codecs ,  criou a própria versão da API WEBRTC... e dessa forma muita coisa so vai rodar no IE e vice-versa .

Comment: @GilmarSantos esqueci de dizer que a tendência é da necessidade de colocar os prefixos ir sumindo a medida que o padrão é estabelecido e as novas versões dos browsers são lançadas .

Comment: Tenho outra dúvida, usar algum tipo de CSS hack pode prejudicar o CSS do site ?

Comment: @GilmarSantos pra corrigir o que não rodou em um browser específico não vejo problemas . E o !important usado com moderação pode ser um salvador de tempo .

Answer (score 2):

Um bom começo para assegurar-se que seus sites são compatíveis com os navegadores com os quais você está trabalhando (mas não com todos, pois isso é praticamente impossível, especialmente quando entram em cena navegadores antigos e dispositivos móveis) é verificar a compatibilidade das funcionalidades que você pretende usar.

Uma boa ferramenta para isso é o [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com). A [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/) também cita a compatibilidade com navegadores nas páginas de documentação.

Usar uma biblioteca pronta também te exime do trabalho de lidar com as particularidades de cada navegador em várias funcionalidades importantes. [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), por exemplo, é muito usada para facilitar o uso de AJAX e de manipulação do DOM.

Comment: O melhor é não precisar disso, mas, se resolver o seu problema, use o que estiver disponível. Mas certifique-se de entender por que uma coisa funciona e por que não funciona. Tente entender qual é o jeito certo de fazer, mesmo que ele não seja universal, porque ele te garante o futuro daquele código.

Answer (score 2):

Olha cara Deixar um site compatível para todos os Browsers não é um trabalho muito fácil porque cada browser tem seu modo de trabalhar e processar cada código: javascript, html,css, Etc.
Mas para que você possa desenvolver um site que ficará com a probabilidade maior de que vá funcionar em todos/ou/grande maioria dos browsers é desenvolvendo o seu site seguindo o padrão W3C.

**O que seria o padrão W3C?** (W3C) é a principal organização de padronização da World Wide Web, Ou seja ele é o padrão do conteudo web, Os navegadores(Browsers) são feitos seguindo esse padrão.

No próprio site da W3C é possível achar tutorias/dicas sobre html/css E se eu não me engano eles também disponibiliza uma ferramentazinha no site que você coloca a URL do seu site e verifica se ele está com algum erro comparado com a padronização W3C.

Espero que tenha dado para entender direitinho, Se foi oque você precisava só marcar a resposta como: Melhor Resposta.
E caso precise de mais algumas informações Deixe nos comentários que eu estarei editando a pergunta e tentando responder suas dúvidas de forma clara.
Site W3C: www.w3c.br/

Comment: Seria bom eu validar meu código CSS e html no site da w3c ?

Comment: Sim. O uso de ferramentas de auxílio ao código como CSS Lint e ESLint também pode te dar pistas de possíveis erros. Leia com atenção as recomendações e tente entender por que uma coisa deve ou não ser feita de uma certa forma.